# Does bytes.Buffer perform a lot of reallocs?

Tags: memory-management, go

What I'm trying to do is have a `io.MultiWriter` that writes to a stdout and to a byte buffer.  Something like this:

```
package main

import "bytes"
import "fmt"
import "io"
import "os"

func main() {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    multi := io.MultiWriter(&b, os.Stdout)
    fmt.Fprintf(multi, "each of these strings\n")
    fmt.Fprintf(multi, "might be large\n")
    fmt.Fprintf(multi, "and there are many of them\n")
    fmt.Println(b.String())
}
```

What I'm wondering is if I'm shooting myself in the foot by doing this?  Does this re-alloc the array for every insert into it? and if so, perhaps there is a better way?  Am I prematurely optimizing?

Comment: Not trying to be snarky, but you can always read the [source](https://golang.org/src/bytes/buffer.go?s=402:854#L7) too.

Comment: You're right, and Go's source code is actually *very* readable :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be the standard way to write to a bytes buffer.

`bytes.Buffer` type grows similar to slices. So a buffer, which is a byte slice internally, doubles each time the data going into it exceeds the current byte slice's capacity. Then the data from old slice is copied over to this new slice after which new data is appended to it.

This algorithm on average performs in constant time (amortized), so there is no major performance penalty.

Comment: Re: "performs linearly"... Linear complexity is O(n).  The buffer expansion method of doubling the capacity produces amortized constant time complexity or O(1).  Nominally, an insert operation runs in O(1) with occasional expansions costing O(n).  The amortized cost becomes O(1).

Comment: Also, be aware that the expansion method is actual twice the current capacity _**plus**_ the size of the desired growth (length of string being inserted).  Inserting 500 bytes into an empty buffer allocates 500 bytes.  Inserting 500 bytes into a buffer that currently has 100000 bytes allocates 200500 bytes.  For a long running, logging application like the OP suggests, this might lead to a panic if the buffer is not being drained.

Comment: Also, be aware of the small buffer optimization that exists.  there is a static buffer (64 bytes?) that is part of the bytes type.  This buffer is used until exhausted.   A single allocation of a bytes instance allocates 64 bytes storage at the same time.

Comment: Noted. Implementation details can be found here. They are pretty straight forward: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/bytes/buffer.go#L87